# Silverlight width smooth animation

Tags: .net, silverlight, animation

I have container with textblock content. Textblock text will be changed to any text. I need to change size of container with animation. What the best way to do it?

Example

from:
[hello world text]
to:
[hello]

with animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should animate the container's width from code when you are updating the text of your TextBlock:

```
// right before updating the text:
textBlock.Text = "hello";
textBlock.UpdateLayout();
// animation is a DoubleAnimation
animation.From = container.ActualWidth;
animation.To = textBlock.ActualWidth;
// storyBoard is a Storyboard that contains animation and targets container.Width
storyBoard.Begin();
```

I fear you cannot do this only with XAML.